# Find periods relations in list using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a class which contains date information about period, Start and End:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

then I have a List of objects A where I declared a few periods:

```
List<A> listOfA = new List<A>()
{
     new A {Id=1,Name="1", Start = new DateTime (2020,1,1), End = new DateTime(2020,1,20) },
     new A {Id=2,Name="2", Start = new DateTime (2020,1,21), End = new DateTime(2020,2,20) },
     new A {Id=3,Name="3", Start = new DateTime (2020,5,11), End = new DateTime(2020,5,14) },
     new A {Id=4,Name="4", Start = new DateTime (2020,5,15), End = new DateTime(2020,5,20) }
};
```

I want to find relation (overlapping, containing etc.) betwen given periods and periods in list:

```
var wrong = new A { Id = 5, Name = "5", Start = new DateTime(2020, 1, 3), End = new DateTime(2020, 4, 20) };
var ok = new A { Id = 6, Name = "6", Start = new DateTime(2020, 4, 3), End = new DateTime(2020, 4, 14) };
```

In above example wrong object have Start date inside one of the object in list and ok object have no relation. How to find that relation using LINQ?

Comment: Using `Any` or `Aggregate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quadratic time complexity and totally untested, however it looks good and that's what counts

```
var results = list.Where(x => 
                    list.Any(y =>
                         x != y && 
                         (x.Start >= y.Start && x.Start <= y.End ||
                         x.End <= y.End && x.End >= y.Start)))
                  .ToList();
```

Or

**Given**

```
public class A
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public DateTime Start { get; set; }
     public DateTime End { get; set; }

     public bool Intersect(A a)
        => this != a && (Start >= a.Start && a.Start <= a.End || End <= a.End && End >= a.Start);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var wrong = list.Where(x => list.Any(x.Intersect)).ToList();
var good = list.Except(wrong).ToList();
```

Comment: How to use that? By adding wrong result on the end of a list and check if results are not empty (this means that there is relation)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
var wrong2 = listOfA.Any(i => wrong.End > i.Start && wrong.Start < i.End);
var ok2 = listOfA.Any(i => ok.End > i.Start && ok.Start < i.End);
```

"wrong2" will be true (overlap).
"ok2" will be false (no overlap).

Edit : You should maybe consider to create a "Period" object that would have "StartDate" and "EndDate" and a "IsOverlapping" method. Result would be the same but more readable :-) (See : [ValueObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20value,money%20or%20a%20date%20range.)).